# SDL2 OpenGL window shrinking and changing mouse coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl

After shrinking my applications to window size mouse coordinates won't change. Graphics work fine, just mouse coordinates are problem.

My applications native size is 1920x1080. But I wan't to shrink app to 1280x720.

Here is what I'm doing right now:

1. Create window with 1280x720 w/h

   `appWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(GAME_TITLE, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS | SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED);`
2. I set glViewport to match with window

   `glViewport(0,0,1280,720);`
3. I make set glOrtho with native size 1920x1080

   `glOrtho(0, 1920, 1080, 0, -1, 1);`

Like I already said, by doing this graphics do scale on new window size but mouse coordinates don't change and i need to know how to change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure i understand your question, but i think here is problem: glOrtho() is opengl comand not sdl, so it affects opengl graphics only. Mouse and windowing is controlled by SDL in your case.

I dont understand what you are trying to do by saying "My applications native size is 1920x1080. But I wan't to shrink app to 1280x720." if you want to resize window use [SDL_SetWindowSize](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowSize). And then adjust opengl viewport and projection with glViewport and glOrtho, so your opengl view and sdl window size is in sync.

**Edit 1:** If you want to render as it is now, by using larger view than windows, then you need to calculate mouse position by your self. sdl gives you mouse relative to window size not opengl view and projection. Math should be quite simple if you are just scaling the view.

**Edit 2:**  in your case glOrtho(0, 1920, 1080, 0, -1, 1) projects 1920x1080 image to glViewport(0,0, 1280 ,720) view. So it scales down if i am not mistaken. So you need to scale mouse pos down to relative to scale ratio:

untested code:

```
mouseX= 1920.0/1280.0 * winMouse.x
mouseY= 1080.0/720.0 * winMouse.y;
```

I ussually experiment alot, so just try to understand what opengl does and experiment.

Comment: I use OpenGL for rendering. Basically I want to scale graphics for other resolutions also. That I already was succesful to make. However I need to scale mouse coordinates to that resolution aswell.

Comment: Yes, exactly thats what i need, to calculate mouse position on new size. Can u help with that code?

Comment: Tried code that you said, however it did not do anything :O
I use SDL_Point as mousePos, and I calculate mouseposition like this if(Event->type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
        {
            mousePos.x = 1920 / 1080 * Event->button.x;
            mousePos.y = 1080 / 720 * Event->button.y;
        }

Comment: you access wrong event, use Event->motion.x instead of Event->button.x.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, However still its not accurate O_O

Comment: like i said i ussually experiment with this kind of math stuff. if mouse moves faster than graphics cord thats means it needs to be divided with something and so on. Try everything that makes sense. Try swap those division nubers like so:
1920.0/1280.0 to 1280.0 /1920.0.